# Fractional Laplacian and chain rule

Tags: reference-request, fa.functional-analysis, ap.analysis-of-pdes, elliptic-pde, fractional-calculus

For the classical Laplacian, we have
$$\Delta (h(u)) = h'\Delta u + h''(u)|\nabla u|^2$$
for smooth functions $h$ and $u$.

Does a similar chain rule hold (up to a reminder term) also for the fractional Laplacian? In other words, I'm looking for something like
$$(-\Delta)^s (h(u)) =  h'(-\Delta)^{s}  u + h''(u)|(-\Delta)^{s/2} u|^2 + R$$
where $s \in (0,1)$ together with a good estimate (in some norm) for the reminder $R$.